# Can't reverse geolocate using lat/long - throws type errors

Tags: objective-c, geolocation, cllocation

I am able to get the user latitude and longitude and display them correctly in the console log... but I can't reverse geolocate to a city name or anything with them.

What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *userlatitude = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *userlongitude = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-2];        
    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:userlatitude longitude:userlongitude];

    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation: loc completionHandler: ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
         NSLog(@"Currently located at %@",locatedAt);
     }];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

I have also tried replacing `CLLocation *userlatitude .... objectAtIndex:location.count-2];` with

```
CLLocationDegrees userlatitude = [[locations lastObject] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees userlongitude = [[locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-2] doubleValue];
```

but this returns an error during runtime (even though it does not show any syntax errors in the code editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didUpdateLocations method returns a array of [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) objects containing the location data. This array always contains at least one object representing the current location.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)[locations lastObject] // pass the most recent value
              completionHandler: ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"reverse error: %@", error);
                      // handle error here
                      return;
                  }

                  CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                  NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]
                                         componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

                  NSLog(@"Currently located at %@",locatedAt);

    }];

}
```